# Changing norm between $\ell^2$ and $\ell^\infty$.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lp-spaces

For two finite sets $A$ and $B$, let $x_{i,j}$ be in both $\ell^2(A)$ and $\ell^\infty(B)$. Then is it possible that
$$
\| \|x_{i,j} \|_{\ell^\infty(B)}\|_{\ell^2(A)} = \| \|x_{i,j} \|_{\ell^2(A)}\|_{\ell^\infty(B)}
$$
or inequality
$$
\| \|x_{i,j} \|_{\ell^\infty(B)}\|_{\ell^2(A)} \le C\, \| \|x_{i,j} \|_{\ell^2(A)}\|_{\ell^\infty(B)}
$$
holds for some $C$?

I tried to use the $\ell^p$ inclusion for counting measure, which is $\ell^\infty \subset\ell^1 \subset \ell^2$ but I cannot conclude it. Can I have some hint or counterexample (if it is false)?

**EDIT:** The $x_{i,j}$ are decomposed vectors of some vector $x\in \mathbb{R^n}$ by $$x=\sum_{i\in A} \sum_{j\in B} x_{i,j}.$$

Comment: You are taking the $l^2(\mathbb R^n)$ norm of a scalar?

Comment: By $\Vert x_{i,j} \Vert_{\ell^p(\mathbb{R}^n)}$ do you mean the vector in $\mathbb{R}^m$ whose $j$th component is $\Vert \langle x_{1,j}, \dots, x_{n,j} \rangle \Vert_{\ell^p(\mathbb{R}^n)}$?

Comment: I edited. it was so weird.

Comment: Unfortunately I still don't understand what $\Vert x_{i,j} \Vert_{\ell^\infty(B)}$ means; we only know that each $x_{i,j} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and that we're supposed to have $\Vert x_{i,j} \Vert_{\ell^\infty(B)} \in \ell^2(A)$.

Comment: @diracdeltafunk Sorry, I can't explain clearly though I thought a few times. I feel I have to study deeply.  This question is come from spherical harmonics and Littlewood-Paley-Stein theorem. I roughly think your first comment is right, btw.

Comment: Understanding the question you're asking is definitely the first step to trying to answer it :) You should make sure not to move past this in your studies until you fully understand what's going on here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$C=\sqrt n$ works. Just use the fact that $\|y\|_2\leq \sqrt n \|y\|_{\infty}$ to see that LHS is dominatted by $\sqrt n$ times the same expression where both norms are replaced by $\|.\|_{\infty}$. The inequality then becomes obvious.